# How to use Javascript Session and Javascript Session Storage

Tags: javascript, session, storage

,Hi all,

I have been looking for Javascript session for my live chat program.

i want to storage my messages to javascript session live for my chat.

Do you have any example or code something will show me to do this ?

Comment: Unless you're chatting with yourself, you'll need some sort of server back-end, Javascript isn't enough

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var message = new Message('Kishor', 'This is test message.');

sessionStorage.setItem('message', JSON.stringify(message));

function Message(Name, Message){
    this.Name= Name;
    this.Message = Message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you mean cookie or [localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)?